# How to deal with null (missing) values in a deedle series in C#?

Tags: c#, dataframe, deedle

How should I deal with missing values in a deedle series?

For example, I have a series with fields `Name` and `BirthDate`, where `BirthDate` is initially `DateTime?` and I need to convert `BirthDate` to `String`.

```
var newDOB = df.GetColumn<DateTime?>("DOB").Select(x => x.Value.Value != null ? x.Value.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : " ");
df.ReplaceColumn("DOB", newDOB);
```

This is what I tried and it does not work.
What is the best way to convert a missing `DateTime?` value to `string` for me?
And what is the best way in general to deal with missing values in Deedle series and Deedle dataframes in C#?

Comment: What is `df` ? Is it a datatable? If so a column can has only items of the same type.

Comment: Df is a deedle frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are creating a Deedle series, Deedle detects invalid values and treats them as missing automatically - so when you create a series with `NaN` or `null`, those are automatically turned into missing values (and this also works for nullables).

Furthermore, the `Select` method skips over all missing values. For example, consider this series:

```
Series<int, DateTime?> ds = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(i => 
  new KeyValuePair<int, DateTime?>(i, i%5==0 ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.Now.AddHours(i))
 ).ToSeries();
ds.Print();
```

Here, Deedle recognizes that every fifth value is missing. When you call `Select`, it applies the operation only to valid values and every fifth value remains as a missing value:

```
  ds.Select(kvp => kvp.Value.Value.ToString("D")).Print();
```

If you want to do something with the missing values, you could use `FillMissing` (to fill them with a specified string or to copy the value from previous item in the series) or `DropMissing` to discard them from the series. You can also use `SelectOptional` that calls your function with `OptionalValue<V>` and so you can implement your own custom logic for missing values.

This also means that if you have `Series<K, DateTime?>`, it is really not very useful, because the `null` values are all handled by Deedle - so you can turn it into `Series<K, DateTime>` using `Select(kvp => kvp.Value.Value)` and let Deedle handle missing values for you.