# Deedle "blank" values

Tags: c#, visual-studio, deedle

My app downloads some data from a server and joins all of the data into a Deedle.Frame, but one column has just one info and I can't access it.

It throws an exception when I try to access this specific column:

> System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'.

When I print the frame this is the result:

[image: Deedle output]

It seems that deedle isn't filling with "missing".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with null (missing) values in a deedle series in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31973143/how-to-deal-with-null-missing-values-in-a-deedle-series-in-c)

Comment: I tried what's in this post... Still the same error and I can't access the info. It`s just for this column, the rest of them works.

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to bugs related to handling missing value.

https://github.com/fslaborg/Deedle/issues/441

https://github.com/fslaborg/Deedle/issues/439

issue 439 is fixed but 441 is pending on an issue in FSharp.Data that's waiting to be merged. After that, we'll release a new version to fix this problem.